# Get form parent from a widget

Tags: javascript, forms, dojo, dijit.form

Given a dojo input widget (any form widget), what's the best way to obtain the widget's form element? i.e. parent element.

i.e. I am looking to complete a function like this:

```
function getForm(widget) {

    return ( /**code goes here **/);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since form widgets can also be used outside forms, the only way I can think of is the same as you would do without widgets: get a starting dom node and move up until you get to a form node:

```
function find_ancestor_of_type(ancestorTag, node){
    while(node && node.tagName !== ancestorTag){
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
}

function get_form(widget){
    return fund_ancestor_of_type("form", widget.domNode);
}
```

(I havent tested this yet though)

---

By the way, why do you need to do this? Most of the times you can put most of the logic in the form itself (it can also be a dijit.form.Form if you want) and the input widgets don't need to know anything about it.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I know you said you didn't test it but this doesn't work in Dojo. First, you can't use .tagName because that will return something like "div" (considering that's how most widgets are made of, including the form). Also, you said that widgets can be used outside forms, which I agree but I don't see how your solution would work either given that it is looking at ancestor tags, which would imply that the widget is indeep wrapped in a form :)... anyhow, I'll post an answer to my question which worked for me and I'll accept your solution anyway.

Answer (score 5):

If you are simply looking for the form element, you might be better off finding the input (or other form content element) and use its form property.  Something like the following

```
function getForm(widget) {
   var inputNode = widget.valueNode || widget.focusNode;
   if (inputNode) return inputNode.form;
   return null;
}
```

would work for the widgets I looked at.  Might miss on some widgets, but don't think you could get a false positive.

Answer (score 1):

If the form is a dijit/form/Form, you could use dijit/registry to get the form (the widget not just the DOM node).

```
require( ["dijit/registry"], function( registry )
{
    var formWidget = registry.getEnclosingWidget( registry.byId('form_element_id').domNode );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are curious, this is what worked for me:

```
function getForm(widget) {

    return (widget.domNode.parentNode);
}
```